# Contour lines of a function including critical points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

The problem that I have to solve sounds like this:

> Sketch the level contours of $f(x,y)$ in a region including all the
>   critical points where $f(x,y)$ = $4x^2y + 4x^2+y^2-2y+1$

I know that the level sets or the set of contours is:

- $L_C = \{ \forall c \in R | f(x,y) = c \}$

I managed to break down the problem into:

- $f(x,y) = 4x^2(y+1) + (y-1)^2 = c \to f(x,y) = (\frac{2x\sqrt{y+1}}{\sqrt{c}}) ^2 + (\frac{y-1}{\sqrt c})^2 = 1$

But from here I am lost..I just don't know how to plot hyperbolae. I would loove to get insight in how to solve this, thanks!!

Comment: Well, the $x^2y$ term is degree three so I wouldn't expect a hyperbola. I suppose you could solve for $x$ as a function of $y$ fairly easily to get the square root of a rational function. Shouldn't be too hard to graph the rational function and then distort that graph under the square root.

Comment: @MarkMcClure If I solve x as a fn o y where does c go?